# The audio file isn't being found/recognised in my My.Resources but it is there

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This is for a quiz game that I am doing for a class assignment and I am a beginner in using both Visual Studio and the language vb.net.

I am trying to get this sound to play when the form comes up, that's all. The file itself plays fine when I click on it.

Error: 'crowdbooing' is not a member of 'VS_BeatTheBrain_JKEM.My.Resources'.

My Code:

```
Public Class frm_loser
Friend WithEvents player As New System.Media.SoundPlayer
Private Sub frm_loser_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    player.Stream = My.Resources.crowdbooing
    player.Play()
End Sub 
End Class
```

I have checked and the audio file (.wav) is definitely in the resource folder, I have already tried:

- Removing it and re-adding it
- Re-downloaded it
- Tried another computer
- Teacher tried it on theirs and it worked (the code, I believe they used a different audio file but from the same source that I got mine from)
- Renamed it
- Searched the internet for a solution
- Tried changing 'Build Action' property on audio file to either 'None' or 'Embedded Resource' or 'Resource'. (Didn't Work)

[Proof Audio File is in Resources, As Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsOmZ.png)

[Proof 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWifh.png)

[What it shows when I hover over the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oxz0.png)

Update: Problem has not been solved on the original project. Created a new project, copy & pasted forms from original into the new one and the sound now works.

Comment: In the "Solution Explorer" pane, right-click the "crowdbooing.wav" file and choose "Properties." I tried with the "Build Action" set to "None", and also with it set to "Embedded Resource", and both options worked when I tested it. With it set to "Embedded Resource", you should see the size of the .exe increase by the size of the .wav file.

Comment: Oh, and make sure to set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project and as the default for new projects.

Comment: I have tried this but the same error is still coming up, Thanks.

Comment: Can you access other files in `My.Resources` ?